# PHP-Can't understand what is happening in this line of code

Tags: php, vb.net, loops

```
        for($reg3=0; $reg3<128; $reg3++)
        {
             $reg1[$reg3] = $reg1[$reg3] ^ ($reg6[$reg3+256] & 1);
        }
```

I really don't understand what is happening here `$reg1[$reg3] ^ ($reg6[$reg3+256] & 1);`
and what would be it's vb.net equivalent code.

Comment: Rollback: The OP asks what the equivalent would be in `vb.net`, so I assume the tag has a right to be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is performing a [bitwise XOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) between two operands, one of which is produced by applying a [bitwise AND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) to two other operands. Other than that, it's standard array indexes and addition.

The VB.Net code would be exactly the same *if the types of the expressions support these operators* (we don't know what the values of the variables are).

Answer (score 1):

`^` and `&` are binary/bitwise operators - more here: [Bitwise Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

`^` - Xor (exclusive or)
`&` - And

I'm guessing this is recompiled code or obfuscated - if not, thems some horrible variable names.

Switching for more traditional variable names: `$reg3`->`$i`, `$reg1`->`$a`, `$reg6`->`$b` we get:

```
for($i=0; $i<128; $i++) {
   $a[$i] = $a[$i] ^ ($b[$i+256] & 1);
}
```

It goes through the first 128 elements of array (or perhaps string) `$a`.  For each element, XOR it (`^ ($b...`) with the last bit only (`& 1`) of an element in array (or string) `$b` that is 256 places further on.  `$a` must be at least 128 elements, `$b` must be at least 384 elements.

Answer (score 1):

& is a bitwise **AND** operator.

^ is a bitwise **XOR** operator.